# view render - backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How do I make this result in backbone.js    result wanted `<p><h3>fgfdgdfg</h3></p>`

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'p',
    render: function () {
        $('body').append(this.$el.html("<h3>fgfdgdfg</h3>"));
    }
});

var todoView = new TodoView();
todoView.render();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `tagName` instead of `el`.
Edited to fix bad html, [thanks @muistooshort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074185/834178).  Just removed the `<p>` altogether.

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:'h3',
    render: function () {
        $('body').append(this.$el.html("fgfdgdfg"));
    }

});

var todoView = new TodoView();
todoView.render();
```

You set `el` if there is an existing DOM element you want the view to use.  Setting `tagName` tells Backbone to generate an 'h3' element for the view's root.

You could do this, also (I prefer this way; avoid setting 'el'):

```
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:'h3',
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html("fgfdgdfg");
        return this;
    }

});

// view is more reusable now, since it doesn't have the 'body' part in render.
// So, another instance could be rendered and added to the page somewhere else.
var todoView = new TodoView();
$('body').append(todoView.render().el);
var todoView2 = new TodoView();
$('body').append(todoView2.render().el);
```

If your html already had the 'h3' element you wanted to use for the view, you could do this:

```
// assuming this html on the page already:
// <body><h3></h3></body>
var TodoView = Backbone.View.extend({

    // setting 'el' tells backbone to use the existing <h3>.
    // You probably would want to use an id rather than 'h3' though.
    el:'h3',
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html("fgfdgdfg");
        return this;
    }

});

var todoView = new TodoView();
todoView.render();
```

Comment: Sort of. El is DOM element, which is basically acting like a wrapper for your rendered content. By default, its a DIV, but you can change its type using tagName as Paul has pointed out.

Comment: Whether or not this works depends on the browser, `<p><h3>X</h3></p>` is not valid HTML so some browsers will correct it to `<p></p><h3>X</h3><p></p>` (or similar) behind your back.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't because `<p><h3>fgfdgdfg</h3></p>` is not valid HTML and the browser will often attempt to correct invalid HTML.

From the [fine `<p>` specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html):

> **Permitted contents**
>
> [Phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content)

And [phrasing content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/terminology.html#phrasing-content) is:

> **phrasing content**
>
> Consists of [phrasing elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) intermixed with [normal character data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#normal-character-data).

[*Normal character data*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#normal-character-data) is, more or less, just plain text without markup so `<h3>` won't be in there. [*Phrasing elements*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing) are simple things like `<a>`, `<b>`, `<img>`, ... and there is no `<h3>` in there either.

You'll have to fix your HTML if you want consistent results. Then, once you have valid HTML in mind, [Paul's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15073798/479863) should get things finished.